# Extracting year with max value for calendar day Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with daily readings of lake level and temperature.  I want to extract the max level for each day of the year, along with the year that the reading occurred.  If it occurred more than once on the same day of the year, I'd like the first occurrence.  It's easy enough to get the max for each day, but I haven't been able to also extract the year.  I'm sure there are other people much more versed in GSheets than me who can figure this out.  I also expect it's not that difficult, but I've yet to be able to find something that works.

Here's the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kC3L0oDpnnJlFFuB76mUXiz3vGcfT5_fC3YbkE9Xgsg

Comment: I figured it out, although it's certainly not the fastest way, nor probably the most elegant.  Here's what I used: =query(A:B, "select B, A where month(A)+1 =1 and day(A)=1 order by B desc, A asc limit 1").  I then formatted the column with the resulting date to only show the year.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do: Are you trying to get the maximum temperature of each day? Or just trying to find the absolute highest temperature and know which year was that?

Comment: For each day of the calendar year, I want the max level, and the year it occurred in.  The data starts in 1907, so there's at least 114 data points for each calendar day (i.e. Jan 25).  The solution I came up with is quite slow, but it does work, so there's that.  It's much easier to do this with a database, as we've done in the past, but we have to move away from those due to requirements from our headquarters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
The layout you needed was a little different than what I'd first thought.
This QUERY will generate the maximum and minimums per day for your data.
[link to sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BLSwjJzWx8s-dnMagr4jhMovPrIMutkWhmYKZaarjgM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({1*(TEXT('raw data'!A2:A,"mmm d ")&2020),IF('raw data'!B2:C=0,,'raw data'!B2:C)},"select Col1,MAX(Col2),MIN(Col2),MAX(Col3),MIN(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1 label Col1'Day'"))
```

Then this formula will use those days and values to do a VLOOKUP back into the Raw Data to show the first year on which that value occurred for that day.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(N(C4:D)&TEXT(B4:B,"mmm d"),{'raw data'!B:B&TEXT('raw data'!A:A,"mmm d"),YEAR('raw data'!A:A)},2,0))
```

This spreadsheet will be available forever.